# How to use Tree in powershell for zipped files

Tags: python, powershell, tree, zip

I am looking to use a command line script or even a python coded script for a tree type function for files that are already zipped. I burn files onto discs and finalize them for work requirements. Some files need to be zipped for transfer.

When using “Tree /f /a” I get a good output of the files I am looking for, but if a zipped file is on the disc, it does not do a break down of the contents in the zipped file. I don’t see any other modifiers for tree that can tree out a zipped file. Does anyone know what I can pipe to (or help me build a script in python or C) that can tree a directory and tree zipped files in that directory?

I’m not good at coding, so forgive me for my novice abilities with coding. I know a python code will have to pull the directory, tree it out. it’ll need some “if” and maybe some “when” statements when it finds a zip file to unzip the file, tree out the file. Then continue onto the next file in the directory until all files have been treed.

The files are always located on a finalized/closed disc, so I’m not even sure if you can unzip a file to tree it. Let alone zip it back up? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Typically I do this to tree out the disc in the disc tray, but it doesn’t tree zipped files. I always output the tree into a .txt file for review and file transfer archives.

“tree /f /a d:/ > c:/filetransfer/transfer/“date”/transfer.txt”

Comment: You can definitely read the contents of a zip file in PowerShell with the `system.io.compression.filesystem` type, but converting them to a tree format sounds like more work than it's worth.

Comment: `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead('zipfile.zip').Entries.FullName` (powershell 6+).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a super rudimentary bit of code that will tree things out in PowerShell. It could definitely use some polish to draw all the pretty lines that Tree does, but it will at least expand out zip files.

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
Function Tree-Path($Path){
    ('  -  '*($Path.Split('\/').Count -1))+$Path.Split('\/')[-1]
}
Function Tree-ZipFile($ZipFilePath){
    $ZipFile = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($ZipFilePath)
    $ZipFile.Entries.FullName|Group {($_ -replace '/[^/]+$').TrimEnd('/')}|%{
        Tree-Path ("$ZipFilePath\"+$_.Name)
        $_.Group|Select -skip 1|%{Tree-Path "$ZipFilePath\$_"}
    }
    $ZipFile.Dispose()
}

GCI D:\ -Recurse|% -begin {$_.Parent} -process {
    If($_.Extension -eq '.zip'){
        Tree-Path $_.FullName
        Tree-ZipFile $_.FullName
    }Else{
        Tree-Path $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the advice. I definitely wouldn’t have made any code like that and had no idea where to start. I’m on the security side of the house, so I don’t know much about this realm. We run isolated systems, and anything that helps is worth the time, rather than hand jamming file paths individually on paper for each piece of data transferred to/from the system. I’ll see if I can implement this code and will reach back out if there are any issues.

Comment: To be honest, you may be just as well off running `Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse |% FullName` which would just give you the full path of everything on the drive.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, your command would not drill in to zip files, which is the main point of the question.